# Regex to match items within a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write regex to check whether items within a string meet a certain criteria:

It needs to be a letter followed by a number:

```
'a' then a number 0-7
```

and

```
'b' then a number 0-6
```

For example:

- String "a7b6" should be valid, but
- String "a7b7" should be invalid (because b is followed by 7, which is out of the range 0-6), and
- String "60" should be invalid (because both items are numbers)

I have currently written:

```
[a0-7[b0-6]]+
```

but this expression also validates "a7b7" and "60".

I've also tried:

```
[a\\d&&[^8-9]]+
```

This captures "a7" and "60"; im not sure what to add in to capture the "b6" part and ignore the "60"

EDIT: To add the fact that the order of the string is not fixed, it may be "a7b6", "b3a6", or "b2a1" etc.

Comment: You are not supposed to use character group `[]`. Use `()` instead.

Comment: Well,you overcomplicated it all. Use `s.matches("a[0-7]|b[0-6]")` (something like this, or `"a[0-7](?:b[0-6])?|b[0-7]"`, or even `"(?:a[0-7]|b[0-6])+"`).

Comment: And why are you using `&&`? That (most of the time) doesn't do what you expect in Regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Post as answer please?

Comment: I would omit the `|` as OP wants to check the whole string (at least in his examples). Also `b[0-7]`is wrong

Comment: I will post if OP confirms at least one of the 3  solutions in my comment work. Right now, the requirements are unclear to me.

Comment: Probably, you may also use `a[^0-7]|b[^0-6]` and if found, the input is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your examples, you're searching just for

```
a[0-7]b[0-6]
```

which is an a, followed by a digit from 0 to 7, followed by b and 0 to 6.

- ab6 would be false
- a4b7 would be false
- a4  would be false
- a2b0 would be right.

To allow multiple of these, chained together, like

- a4b4a3b5

You would group them, and write

```
(a[0-7]b[0-6])+
```

Your subconstruct [b0-6] for instance means b or 0 or 1, ... or 6, not b followed by something.

I've never seen nested sets, like `[a-z[^np]]`, which might look useful sometimes (a-z, except...) - I doubt they're valid.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is close, but what if the order were to change, for example "b3a6"?

Comment: then use wiktors answer with the `|`

Comment: @APotatoUsingR: Then you have to specify, whether the first digit might be 0-7 and the second 0-6, or the digit following a might be 0-7 and the one following b 0-6. Here: `(a[0-7]b[0-6])|(b[0-6]a[0-7])`the 7 possibility is bound to a, here `(a[0-7]b[0-6])|(b[0-7]a[0-6])` to the first position.

Answer (score 0):

`[…]` is the syntax for character classes, allowing for any one of the chracters inside. You want something a little different:

```
(a[0-7]|b[0-6])+
```

`(…)`is the syntax for a group.

Comment: you should omit the `+`

Comment: Not sure that i should. The OP has only given one valid example; going from there it could be omitted. But the phrasing of the question, along with the fact that `+` appeared in both the attempts, suggests this might be what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the meaning of [].
Now when you write [abc] it implies set definition can match the letter a or b or c.

[a0-7[b0-6]]+ would mean multiple occurrence of a/0-7 and b/0-6.
I would advice you to go through the regex documentation again.

Comment: To come up with the answer you need to define the permitted strings that you want to match, length of the string.
Example:
a7b6c5d4
a7a6a5